# FLASK: The new values entered in the form are not getting inserted to the database even though the execution has been committed

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, url_for, redirect, session, render_template, g
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DATABASE'] = './data.db'

def connect_db():
    path = r"C:\Users\Arjun\Documents\flask_app\data.db"
    sql = sqlite3.connect(path)
    sql.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return sql

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite3'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

@app.route('/home', defaults={'name':'Default'})
@app.route('/home/<name>')
def home(name):
    session['name'] = name
    return render_template('home.html', name=name, display = False, mylist = [1,2,3,4]

@app.route('/theform5', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def theform5():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('form.html')
    else:
        name = request.form['name']
        location = request.form['location']

        db = get_db()
        db.execute("insert into users (name, location) values (?, ?)", [name, location])
        db.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('home', name=name, location=location))

@app.route('/viewresults')
def viewresults():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select id, name, location from users')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    return 'The ID is {}. Name is {}. The location is {}. '.format(results[1]['id'], results[1] 
            ['name'], results[1]['location'])
```

Error in:

> return "The ID is {}. Name is {}. The location is {}".format(results[1]['id'],results[1]['name'],results[1]['location'])

IndexError: list index out of range

Though the table can be edited directly through the terminal, it can't be edited when the flask web app is run.

- Browser: Chrome
- SQLite: v3.30.1
- Python: v3.8.1
- Flask: v1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in your return statement in your home function. missing ')' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run db.execute you would have to set up the cursor first:

db = get_db()

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("insert into users (name, location) values (?, ?)", [name, location])

also, maybe your syntax is off, try this:

cursor.execute("insert into users values('%s', '%s')" %(name, location))

Answer (score 0):

[Are these not the answers you are looking for?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqPIG.png)